# Extract data from an audio or video file and store as text or binary for future analytics

Tags: sql-server, analytics, data-warehouse

Is there is any  way to extract data from an audio or video file and store as text or binary for future analytics or data warehouse activities in MS SQL. From unstructured text documents we can achieve this using **Full Text Search** concept. Is there is any similar approach is  available for audio or video files with latest edition of SQL server?

Comment: Are you looking for some kind of speech recognition? Or do you want to extract some metadata (for example duration, capture date, camera version, sampling rate, resolution)?

Comment: No Morten , I am not expecting a speech recognition. I am thinking a way to capture the text from audio/video files without playing it using SQL. And store that data as a text/binary to our SQL database for future data analytics activities.The documents can be stored  in the database and using Full Text Search Index we can do analytics (word search etc.) without opening that document. Similar approach I am searching for audio/video.